# DLLs imported by default into a C# application

Tags: c#, linker, default

I couldn't find any information on this. Does anyone have a list of all the C# DLLs linked with a C# executable by default (e.g. System.Core.dll)?

I'm using csc.exe to compile C# code.

Comment: I'm assuing you are referring to which .Net framwork assemblies are referenced by default: If you're using Visual Studio (or any other IDE) it depends on the type of project.

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *absolute* minimum "imported dlls" for any C# (and ultimately .NET) program is `mscorlib.dll`. This is always implicitly referenced. It contains the absolute minimum  types needed in the BCL (Base Class Library) and is required for all .NET programs under any language.

If you're wondering what assemblies are referenced by default in Visual Studio, it depends on the project, programming language and version of the framework you're targeting.  These additional assemblies provide additional language support typically and other features not part of the BCL but are generally useful to have available (such as LINQ).

A C# console application targeting .NET 4.0 for example references these assemblies by default (in VS2010):

```
Microsoft.CSharp              (.NET 4.0 and up) (dynamic support)
System                        (all versions)    (everything else in the BCL)
System.Core                   (.NET 3.5 and up) (LINQ and other enhancements)
System.Data                   (all versions)    (ADO.NET)
System.Data.DataSetExtensions (.NET 3.5 and up) (LINQ extensions for ADO.NET)
System.Xml                    (all versions)    (XML)
System.Xml.Linq               (.NET 3.5 and up) (LINQ extensions for XML)
```

If you're planning on writing a basic console application, you probably only really need `System` and `System.Core`.  If you specifically need to work with XML or need to create data sets, then reference the appropriate assemblies.

Comment: Thanks! Thorough and informative answer. :) I actually thought there'd be more default managed references, though I did miss a couple of these.